# Facebook iOS invite doesn't reach the invitee

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdkappinvitecontent

I'm using `FBSDKAppInviteContent` to invite people to my app. I'm able to go through the wizard (after finally resolving an error about my app link which was incorrect, now it's not) and the invite was sent. No hiccups, and the delegate responds with `{didComplete:1}`.

However.. the notification doesn't reach the persons that I want to invite! I have verified:

- My app is Live
- My app has a valid iPhone Store ID
- The app link opens the app

What have I missed?

Comment: Has the invitee had the specific application installed previously?

Comment: no.. inviting a test user

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it with the help from the Facebook Developer Community.

The notification are only sent to the same platform your application is serving. If you have set it to iOS, the user who recieves the invitation will only be noitified on his iOS mobile, not on his Android, nor in the browser, desktop or mobile.

Hope that helps another poor sole!

Comment: Thanks for this, I had the same issue.